# How do I clone ZFS ACLs from one file to another?

Tags: solaris, access-control-list, zfs

I'd like to clone all the ZFS ACLs from one file to another.

With POSIX ACLs this can be done by piping the output of `getfacl` to `setfacl`.

Is there an easy and quick way to do this with the NFSv4 style ACLs in ZFS? I know I can read off the output of `ls -lV` and then enter it as part of a `chmod`, but I can't seem to find a functional equivalent to the POSIX way of copying ACLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `ls -lV` you can use `ls -lv` which can be fed in to a script to convert it to a sequence of `chmod` commands to duplicate the ACLs.

E.g. if the ACl looks like this:

```
$ ls -lv file1
     0:owner@::deny
     1:owner@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/execute
         /write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:allow
     2:group@:read_data/write_data/append_data:deny
     3:group@:execute:allow
     4:everyone@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr
        /write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:deny
     5:everyone@:read_xattr/execute/read_attributes/read_acl/synchronize:allow
```

It should be turned in to the following sequence of `chmod` commands:

```
chmod A0=owner@::deny file2
chmod A1=owner@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/execute/write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:allow file2
chmod A2=group@:read_data/write_data/append_data:deny file2
chmod A3=group@:execute:allow file2
chmod A4=everyone@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:deny file2
chmod A5=everyone@:read_xattr/execute/read_attributes/read_acl/synchronize:allow file2
```

I recently found myself in a situation where a script like the one described above would have been useful, so here's a little Bash script I made (can also be sourced to the shell and run as a function) to print the list of chmod commands necessary to copy the ZFS ACLs from one file to another:

```
#!/bin/bash

acl_as_chmods () {
# print list of chmod commands to copy the ACL entries from '$1' to '$2'
 [[ -a "$1" ]] 2>/dev/null || {
   echo "Valid reference file required." >&2
   return 1
 }
 ls -vd "$1" | {
   read # first line is not ACL information; bypass
   read ACL_entry
     echo -n "chmod A=${ACL_entry#*:}"
   # if no target file was specified as '$2', use 'TARGET' variable at runtime
   while read ACL_entry || { echo " ${2-\$TARGET}"; false; }
   do
     [[ "$ACL_entry" == [0-9]*:* ]] && \
       echo -en " ${2-\$TARGET}\nchmod A${ACL_entry%%:*}+${ACL_entry#*:}" || \
       echo -n "$ACL_entry"
   done
 }
}

## run as script or source function to shell?
__acl_as_chmods () {
 [[ "${FUNCNAME[1]}" == "source" ]] || acl_as_chmods "$@"
}

__acl_as_chmods "$@"
```

Here are a couple example usages and their output for *file1* from above:

```
~$ ./acl_as_chmods.sh file1 file2
chmod A=owner@::deny file2
chmod A1+owner@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/execute/write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:allow file2
chmod A2+group@:read_data/write_data/append_data:deny file2
chmod A3+group@:execute:allow file2
chmod A4+everyone@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:deny file2
chmod A5+everyone@:read_xattr/execute/read_attributes/read_acl/synchronize:allow file2

~$ source acl_as_chmods.sh
~$ acl_as_chmods file1
chmod A=owner@::deny $TARGET
chmod A1+owner@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/execute/write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:allow $TARGET
chmod A2+group@:read_data/write_data/append_data:deny $TARGET
chmod A3+group@:execute:allow $TARGET
chmod A4+everyone@:read_data/write_data/append_data/write_xattr/write_attributes/write_acl/write_owner:deny $TARGET
chmod A5+everyone@:read_xattr/execute/read_attributes/read_acl/synchronize:allow $TARGET
```

If we like, we can even evaluate these chmods directly, if both files are accessible on this host and we wish to copy the ACLs from *file1* to *file2* immediately:

```
~$ ls -Vd file*  #BEFORE
-rwx--x--x   1 user user       0 Jun 19 04:12 file1
            owner@:--------------:------:deny
            owner@:rwxp---A-W-Co-:------:allow
            group@:rw-p----------:------:deny
            group@:--x-----------:------:allow
         everyone@:rw-p---A-W-Co-:------:deny
         everyone@:--x---a-R-c--s:------:allow
---x------+  1 user user       0 Jun 19 04:12 file2
            owner@:--x-----------:------:allow

~$ eval "$(acl_as_chmods file1 file2)"

~$ ls -Vd file*  #AFTER 
-rwx--x--x   1 user user       0 Jun 19 04:12 file1
            owner@:--------------:------:deny
            owner@:rwxp---A-W-Co-:------:allow
            group@:rw-p----------:------:deny
            group@:--x-----------:------:allow
         everyone@:rw-p---A-W-Co-:------:deny
         everyone@:--x---a-R-c--s:------:allow
-rwx--x--x   1 user user       0 Jun 19 04:12 file2
            owner@:--------------:------:deny
            owner@:rwxp---A-W-Co-:------:allow
            group@:rw-p----------:------:deny
            group@:--x-----------:------:allow
         everyone@:rw-p---A-W-Co-:------:deny
         everyone@:--x---a-R-c--s:------:allow
```

Comment: This is probably the closest I'll get. I'll look at automating it somehow as dlamblin suggests.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue. My code is here:

https://gist.github.com/1021032

Works like a charm for me. Hope it's handy if anybody else out there ever runs into this problem.

Comment: Thank you, this should be the accepted solution, because it has no overhead and no problems with parsing. Another interesting function in this regard is `acl_totext(acl_t *, int)`, which gives you a clean comma-separated string of all ACEs - with flag 2 it seems to be the short version, else the long version. The garbage that `ls -v` produces on the other hand is maddening, even 7 years later... (multiple ambiguous newlines sprinkled in depending on amount of permissions set)

Answer (score 1):

Taking what [Martin](https://serverfault.com/users/5977/martin) suggests and applying a bit of perl you might get something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $state = 0;
if ($#ARGV < 1 || $#ARGV > 2) {
  print "\n\tUsage: $0 srcFile destFile\n";
}
my $acl=`ls -lv "${ARGV[0]}"`;
my @out="chmod", "arg", $ARGV[1];
foreach my $line ($acl) {
  chomp $line;
  if ($line =~ m/^\s+(\d+):(.*)$/) {
    if ($state > 0) {
      print join(" ",@out)."\n";
      #system(@out) or die "system @args failed: $?";
    }
    $state = 1;
    $out[1] = "A$1=$2";
  } else {
    $line =~ m/^\s+(.*)$/;
    $state = 2;
    $out[1] .= $1;
  }
}
if ($state > 0) {
  print join(" ",@out)."\n";
  #system(@out) or die "system @args failed: $?";
}
```

try it before uncommenting the system(@out) lines.

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, this doesn't seem to be properly exposed at the shell level.  In C, there are functions `acl_get(3SEC)` and `acl_set(3SEC)` which can be used to take the ACL from one file and apply it to another (among other options, obviously).  They will also, usefully, translate an ACL from POSIX-draft to NFSv4 type; this is what system commands like `mv` and `cp` use.

I wrote, at one time, a command to copy an acl from a source to a destination file using this technique, but I presently cannot find the source code.  Should I find it, I'll append it to this answer.

Comment: Sounds nice. Would definitely like to see that.